# How to forcefully delete a daemonset or a pod in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a `kubernetes` cluster which is working fine. I created `deployment` with type as `daemonset` which then created few pods and it worked fine. I made few changes so I deleted the `daemonset` using:

```
kubectl delete daemonset <name> --namespace=clustech
```

While few pods were getting deleted, few of the machine went offline and thus the pods running on them went on to say `unknown` status. I need to remove those pods or completely remove that previous `daemonset` but unable to do. I am using below commands to delete pods:

```
kubectl delete pod PODNAME --grace-period=0 --force
```

But this shows below error:

```
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
Error from server (NotFound): pods "deployment-6sj54" not found
```

How can I delete the pods.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-run the second command with `namespace` parameter will do your job.

`--grace-period=0 --force` is the right command to delete such pods.

Comment: that also not worked from me ...... admin@ip-172-20-58-79:~/EFK/cloud-infra/k8s/EFK$ kubectl delete ds fluentd -n kube-logging  --grace-period=0 --force
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.

Comment: admin@ip-172-20-58-79:~/EFK/cloud-infra/k8s/EFK$ kubectl get po -n kube-logging
No resources found.
admin@ip-172-20-58-79:~/EFK/cloud-infra/k8s/EFK$ kubectl get ds  -n kube-logging
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                                                               AGE
fluentd   0         0         0         0            0           785b166b-8095-11ea-8414-0607d7cb72ed=785b16b7-8095-11ea-8414-0607d7cb72ed   1h

Comment: it didn't work for me. I got recreated again. How do you delete a daeomonset.apps?

Answer (score 5):

You can delete a daemonset.apps using this command:

`kubectl delete --all daemonset.apps -n <namespace>`

Comment: This works for me. The above mentioned verified solution did not work